# MediaPlayer error (-38,0) - playing sound on every touch

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have about 40 sounds for 40 textViews in my app,some of them do play, but some don't. I already looked up other similar questions, but think mine is different, the textview is highlighted white onpress, and turns black when unpressed, meanwhile the sound of a matching word plays back. the 2 arrays are same in length - each textview word corresponds to a sound.

```
    words = new ArrayList<>() ;//this is the array of textviews
    ArrayList<MediaPlayer>word_sounds = new ArrayList<>();
    w1= MediaPlayer.create(Page12.this, R.raw.sentence10_36);
    w2= MediaPlayer.create(Page12.this, R.raw.sentence10_37);
    w3= MediaPlayer.create(Page12.this, R.raw.sentence10_38);

    word_sounds.add(w1);
    word_sounds.add(w2);
    word_sounds.add(w3);

     for( int i = 0 ; i < words.size();i++){
        final TextView element = words.get(i);
        final MediaPlayer current_sound = word_sounds.get(i);

        try{
        current_sound.prepare();}
        catch (Exception e){}
        current_sound.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                current_sound.start();
            }
        });

        element.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        element.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        current_sound.start();



                        break ;
```